# Variance of two random variables given their variances and covariance.

Tags: probability, expectation, covariance

Y and Z are two random variables. Suppose Var(Y ) = 4, Var(Z) = 16, and Cov(Y, Z) = 3.

What is Var(3Z − 2Y )?

Comment: I assume you meant "$Y$ and $Z$ are two random variables. ..."

Comment: So the simplest way is to utilise the linearity of the expectation and expand brackets and then use the variance and covariance as stated.

Comment: How do I do that without knowing what E(Z) and E(Y) are?

Comment: Use $\mathsf {Var}(Y)=\mathsf E(Y^2)-\mathsf E(Y)^2$ and $\mathsf {Cov}(Y,Z) = \mathsf E(YZ)-\mathsf E(Y)\mathsf E(Z)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're learning from first principles:
$$\begin{align}\mathsf{Var}(3Y-2Z) &= \mathsf E((3Y-2Z)^2)-\mathsf E(3Y-2Z)^2
\\ & \vdots
\end{align}$$

Expand using Linearity of expectation, then use $\mathsf {Var}(Y)=\mathsf E(Y^2)-\mathsf E(Y)^2$ and $\mathsf {Cov}(Y,Z) = \mathsf E(YZ)-\mathsf E(Y)\mathsf E(Z)$, &c. to rearrange in terms of known values.

This will produce a rather elegant formula.

> $\mathsf {Var}(3Y-2Z) = 9\,\mathsf {Var}(Y) - 12\,\mathsf {Cov}(Y,Z)+4\,\mathsf {Var}(Z)$

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought I was stuck without being given E(Y) and E(Z), but when applying the definitions of variance/covariance to the expansion of terms I was able to come up with the answer that matched yours.